# Menu links show/hide content in another div

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to figure out how to write a script where when a link is clicked in the left nav column, it will display text in the right main column. So, when you first arrive to the page, nothing will appear in the main portion of the site. Content(more specifically page) only appears after clicking on a link. When you click on another link, the previous content is hidden, and the new text is displayed.

```
  <div class="nav">


      <ul id="menu">


        <li id="link1"><a href="#">Topic One</a></li>


        <li id="link2"><a href="#">Topic Two</a></li>


        <li id="link3"><a href="#">Topic Three</a></li> 


    </ul>


</div>


<div class="main">


    <div id="page1" class="content">


    <h1>Show Page1</h1>


    </div>


    <div id="page2" class="content">


   <h1>Show Page2</h1>


    </div>


    <div id="page3" class="content">  


   <h1>Show Page3</h1>


    </div>             


</div>
```

Comment: Post your code or fiddle it..

Comment: I want to show .html pages on my dic page1 page2 and page2. ill need help with that too..

Comment: it's possible..But what you want to display on content when you click link's?

Comment: i want to display different pages on every div like
like onclick of TOPIC ONE...i should be able to display page1 similarly on TOPIC TWO page2 and TOPIC THREE page3...
I have 3 pages separately coded.
so how can i accomplish that in their respective div's?

Comment: @Abhi did you get this question from [the jQuery forum - Menu links show/hide content in another div](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/menu-links-show-hide-content-in-another-div)? Your question and code is _exactly_ like that of the poster on that page -- however, the question was asked and answered 3 years ago :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only a few lines with jQuery.  Here's the JSfiddle  - http://jsfiddle.net/dangoodspeed/M3ZhV/  and here's the code:

```
$(function() {
    var curPage="";
    $("#menu a").click(function() {
        if (curPage.length) { 
            $("#"+curPage).hide();
        }
        curPage=$(this).data("page");
        $("#"+curPage).show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This will display the content that you want to if you click the link and hide the other content:

```
$('#link1').click(function(){
    $('#content1').show();
    $('#content2').hide();
    $('#content3').hide();
);
$('#link2').click(function(){
    $('#content2').show();
    $('#content1').hide();
    $('#content3').hide();
);
$('#link3').click(function(){
    $('#content3').show();
    $('#content2').hide();
    $('#content1').hide();
);
```

For example if you click `link1`, `content1` will show and `content2` and `content3` will hide.

Comment: content1,content2,content3 are class name of the 3 div respectively?

Comment: There's a lot of unnecessary repeated code in there.  And it's running extra functions (like trying to hide elements that are already hidden).